# Firefox Android with password storage

Tags: security, password, firefox-for-android

Can you suggest a good solution how I can store my passwords secure with Firefox for Android? Firefox sync has no "cloud storage" which means I have no cloud backup. Keepass2Android with Autofill has a bad user experience. The Autofill pop always needs a long press, password storage unlock (as my device permanently kills the app) and needs to much clicks in general. Sometimes the popup is not even opening on my device. Any good alternatives?

Comment: What do you mean by `Firefox sync has no "cloud storage"`? Firefox sync can use a private Firefox Sync server but you don't have to. You can just use the one provided by Mozilla.

Comment: Mozilla itself warns form using Firefox sync as a backup or storage solution. Google on the other hand advertises its cloud services a reliable storage.

Comment: This is just about reliability if you only use Firefox sync. For backup simply sync the data to a PC and then backup the Firefox user data to different backup types. If something goes wrong you can go offline, restore the backup and reestablish Firefox sync.